# Custom marker different size in different browsers - Google Maps API (v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome, safari

I have an issue with my Google Maps API (v3) integration where Safari and Chrome are displaying the custom marker in different sizes.

I would like to be able to have the image the same size across browsers.

I've tried adjusting scaledSize, does nothing. I've also tried adding size: new google.maps.Size(10, 10), but that doesn't seem to help either. Maybe I'm entering it wrong.

Safari: 
[Safari displays the image at the desired size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcF2a.png)

Google Chrome:
[For some reason Chrome displays the image as a large size.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCOIZ.png)

HTML

```
 <section id="map" class="map cont-100">

  </section>
```

Sass

```
.map
  height: 50rem
  width: 100%
```

JS

```
var map;

function initMap() {
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 16,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.074495, -77.325485),
zoomControl: false,
scrollwheel: false,
streetViewControl: false,
mapTypeControl: false,
mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
styles: [{
  "featureType": "water",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "on"
  }, {
    "color": "#b5cbe4"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "landscape",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#efefef"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.highway",
  "elementType": "geometry",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#83a5b0"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.arterial",
  "elementType": "geometry",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#bdcdd3"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road.local",
  "elementType": "geometry",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#ffffff"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "poi.park",
  "elementType": "geometry",
  "stylers": [{
    "color": "#e3eed3"
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "administrative",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "on"
  }, {
    "lightness": 33
  }]
}, {
  "featureType": "road"
}, {
  "featureType": "poi.park",
  "elementType": "labels",
  "stylers": [{
    "visibility": "on"
  }, {
    "lightness": 20
  }]
}, {}, {
  "featureType": "road",
  "stylers": [{
    "lightness": 20
  }]
}]
});

var iconBase = 'http://cochinamogulos.com/img/';
var icons = {
info: {
  icon: iconBase + 'nexia-favicon.svg'
},
scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(2, 2), // scaled size
origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
};

var features = [{
position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.074495, -77.325485),
type: 'info'
}];
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  var center = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(center);
});
// Create markers.
features.forEach(function(feature) {
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: feature.position,
  icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
  map: map
});
});
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

EDIT:

```
    var logo = {
  url: "http://cochinamogulos.com/img/nexia-favicon.svg",
  size: new google.maps.Size(20,32),
  origin: new google.maps.Size(0,0),
  anchor: new google.maps.Size(0,0),
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.074495, -77.325485),
    icon: logo,
    map: map
  });

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'resize', function() {
  var center = map.getCenter();
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  map.setCenter(center);
});
```

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `InvalidValueError: setIcon: in property origin: not a Point: in property x: not a number`

Comment: Thanks for that, with the correction to point it fixed the error and the image is now properly sized. Amazing, what just one word can do in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to resize the marker here is an example:

```
 var image = 
 {
     url: 'images/beachflag.png',
     size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
     origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(data.LastLat, data.LastLon),
                data: data,
                title: data.Description,
                icon: image
            });
```

Comment: Changing the code removes the custom marker and places Google's default marker there.

Comment: Just insert your own image

Comment: I have linked to my own image. That's not what's showing.

Comment: This is the link to the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j_pinder/2L1rntg5/

Comment: I was not allowed to add a third photo, unfortunately. Let me know if you can access the jsFiddle.